# select rows from data frame base on conditions on many columns

Tags: r

```
library(mlbench)
data("HouseVotes84")
head(HouseVotes84)
df=HouseVotes84[complete.cases(HouseVotes84),]
df[df$Class=='democrat'& df$V1=='y' & df$V2=='n',]
```

what if I want to filter on many of the variables
without having to write as much. For example
if I would like to write `('democrat','y','n', , ,'y','n', ...)` as the specification
where I may choose to not to specify some of the variables. Is there any convenient
way to do this? I tried

```
paste0('df$',names(df),'==',c('democrat','y'))
```

and then

```
df[paste0('df$',names(df),'==',c('democrat','y')),]
```

but it does not work

Comment: I assume enclosing your paste0 with `eval(parse()` should work.

Comment: A better idea could be `with(df, { Class='democrat'  & V1=='y'  & V2=='n' } )` it saves you only the dataset name, but that's the safest way, what you're after (vector as source of values) will be a problem if you want to filter on numeric column at a point as a vector can't mix types.

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to "misuse" the `data.table` syntax for selecting keyed columns (see `vignette("datatable-keys-fast-subset", package = "data.table")`).

```
library(data.table)
dt <- HouseVotes84[complete.cases(HouseVotes84), ]

# define variables to save typing
N <- "n"
Y <- "y"
NY <- c(N, Y)
D <- "democrat"
R <- "republican"
DR <- c(D, R)

setkeyv(dt, names(dt))
key(dt)
# [1] "Class" "V1"    "V2"    "V3"    "V4"    "V5"    "V6"    "V7"    "V8"    "V9"    "V10"   "V11"   "V12"  
#[14] "V13"   "V14"   "V15"   "V16"  
dt[CJ(R, Y, N, NY, NY, Y, N), nomatch = 0]
#        Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
#1: republican  y  n  n  y  y  n  y  n  n   y   n   n   n   y   y   y
#2: republican  y  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  y   n   n   y   y   y   n   y
#3: republican  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  n  y   y   n   n   y   y   n   y

dt[CJ(D, Y, N, NY, NY, Y), nomatch = 0]
#      Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
#1: democrat  y  n  n  n  y  y  n  n  n   n   y   y   n   y   n   y
#2: democrat  y  n  n  n  y  y  y  n  n   y   y   n   n   y   n   y
#3: democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  n  n  n   n   n   n   n   n   n   y
#4: democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  n  n  y   y   n   n   y   y   n   y
#5: democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   n   n   y   n   y

dt[CJ(DR, Y, N, NY, NY, Y), nomatch = 0]
#         Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
# 1:   democrat  y  n  n  n  y  y  n  n  n   n   y   y   n   y   n   y
# 2:   democrat  y  n  n  n  y  y  y  n  n   y   y   n   n   y   n   y
# 3:   democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  n  n  n   n   n   n   n   n   n   y
# 4:   democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  n  n  y   y   n   n   y   y   n   y
# 5:   democrat  y  n  y  n  y  y  y  n  n   n   y   n   n   y   n   y
# 6: republican  y  n  n  y  y  n  y  n  n   y   n   n   n   y   y   y
# 7: republican  y  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  y   n   n   y   y   y   n   y
# 8: republican  y  n  n  y  y  y  n  n  n   n   y   y   y   y   n   n
# 9: republican  y  n  n  y  y  y  n  n  n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n
#10: republican  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  n  y   y   n   n   y   y   n   y
#11: republican  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y  n   y   n   y   n   y   y   y
#12: republican  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y  n   y   y   y   n   y   y   y
```

Answer (score 0):

We can leverage the power of `regex` and the `filter` function in `dplyr`.

Assuming you have a `filter` variable, composed of `n` elements, where `n` is also the number of columns of you target `df` dataframe.

Each elements of the vector will filter the respective columns and `NA`s in the vector will take any value:

For example:

```
filter <- c('democrat, 'y', 'y', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

will give as result all the democrats the voted `y` at the first two, and anything the rest.

```
filter <- c('republican', 'y', 'n', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
filter <- toString(filter) %>% 
    gsub(pattern = 'NA', x = ., replacement = '.+')

df %>% 
    unite(string, Class:V16, sep = ', ', remove = F) %>% 
    filter(grepl(x = string, pattern = filter)) %>% 
    select(-string)

#        Class V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16
# 1 republican  y  n  n  y  y  n  y  y  y   n   n   y   y   y   n   y
# 2 republican  y  n  y  y  y  n  y  n  y   y   n   n   y   y   n   y
# 3 republican  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y  n   y   n   y   n   y   y   y
# 4 republican  y  n  y  y  y  y  y  y  n   y   y   y   n   y   y   y
# 5 republican  y  n  n  n  n  n  y  y  y   y   n   n   n   y   n   y
```

Comment: can you please give some explanation about your code? what it will looks like if you have "numeric" conditions (>,<, etc..)? Thank you in advance!