# Extract value from data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse

If I have a data frame, the standard approach to extracting a value is to use a Boolean/logical expression to match the correct row and column. Example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(letters = letters[1:3], numbers = as.character(c(1, 2, 1)), value=rnorm(3))
subset(df, letters=="c" & numbers=="1")$value
[1] -0.8356286
```

However, stringing together many `==` statements seems a bit kludgey. Another way would be to use row names as keys:

```
Key <- function(...) paste(..., sep="%") # this could be any formatting
row.names(df) <- with(df, Key(letters, numbers))
df[Key("c", "1"), "value"]
[1] -0.8356286
```

In the tidyverse, use of row names is discouraged - what would be the recommended way to match and extract values?

Comment: I don't find this "kludgey". Are you asking how to subset without using `==` ?

Comment: Maybe `df %>% filter(paste(letters, numbers) == "c 1") %>% .$value` ?

Comment: Or `dots <- map2(c('letters', 'numbers'), c('c', '1'), ~lazyeval::interp(~x == y, x = as.name(.x), y = .y); filter_(df, .dots = dots)$value`. Can't say that not "kludgey" though. The _recommended_ way to match and extract is probably `filter(df, letters == 'c', numbers == '1')$value`.

Comment: Or perhaps `df %>% mutate(Key = Key(letters, numbers)) %>% filter(Key == Key('c', '1')) %>% .$value`.

Comment: What if you have data with more than two columns? Would you "key" it every time before subsetting? It may work, but I don't find this very useful (and generally it's an opinion based question)

Comment: Or perhaps `Key2 <- function(x) purrr::map2(c('letters', 'numbers'), x, ~lazyeval::interp(~x == y, x = as.name(.x), y = .y)); filter_(df, .dots = Key2(c('a', '1')))`.

Comment: This is pretty easy using data.tables binary join. Something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(df)[.("c", "1"), value, on = .(letters, numbers)]`. Also, is there any reason why your numbers are actually characters?

Comment: Similar question [select rows from data frame base on conditions on many columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42505643/select-rows-from-data-frame-base-on-conditions-on-many-columns) with 2 answers.